# NLP: spacy getting dependencies

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I'm trying to extract some numbers out of this sentence, but I want to verify that the right number is match up to the right text.

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')  
s2 = 'Revenue from the advertising and subscription business for the first quarter of 2019 was RMB897.0 million (US$133.7 million), representing a 13.9% increase from RMB787.5 million (US$117.3 million) in the corresponding period in 2018.'

doc = nlp(s2)
for w in doc.ents:
    print(w.text, w.label_, w.root)
    for i in w.subtree:
        print("   ", i, i.head)
        for a in i.ancestors:
            print("       ", a, a.head)
```

I want to relate `RMB897.0 million` to `advertising and subscription` but not sure how to do it. Also tried noun chunking.

```
for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
    print(chunk.text, chunk.root.text, chunk.root.dep_,
          chunk.root.head.text)

    for c in chunk.subtree:
        print("   ", c, c.head)
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by relate? Do want to do this for anaphora resolution or for text structuring? Are there any patterns occuring in the data you use? Otherwise just use a dependency parser,  I mean its an easy case, since the complex noun phrase is related to the number by a copular verb.

Comment: I want to check if `RMB897.0` is talking about `advertising and subscription`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to consider your data. If you find certain patterns with the numbers and the related nouns, you may be able to use them to figure out the relation, anyways, this is not really robust.
The better approach would be to use dependency parsing or full parsing algorithms using Part Of Speech tagging (POS) information and probably semantic information on the head verbs. This is a really linguistic task, meaning that you need linguistic information for it. The copular verb indicates that the number is related to the verb argument, so 
extraction and relation is straightforward. Other instances may be less obvious.

Maybe start out doing some collocation analysis of expressions containing numbers and the matrix verbs they occur with (be, amount to, reduce to, increase etc.), then you may be able to use the information of the verbal arguments for the annotation on the relation. Maybe have a look at correference and anaphora resolution, this may help you out.